# Bridge interfaces without IP in Debian

Tags: bridge, debian-wheezy

I need to bridge 2 VLAN's on some different interfaces without IP address.
How i can do this?

```
auto eth4
    iface eth4 inet manual
    up ifconfig eth4 up
    mtu 9000

auto eth4.1320
    iface eth4.1320 inet manual
    post-up ifconfig $IFACE up
    pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down
    mtu 9000

auto eth8
    iface eth8 inet manual
    up ifconfig eth8 up
    mtu 9000

auto eth8.1320
    iface eth8.1320 inet manual
    post-up ifconfig $IFACE up
    pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto br1320
    iface br1320 inet manual
    bridge_ports eth4.1320 eth8.1320
    bridge_stp on
    pre-up brctl addbr $IFACE
    up ifconfig $IFACE up
    down ifconfig $IFACE down
    post-down brctl delbr $IFACE
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Otherwise, testing this configuration would answer everything you need to know.

Comment: @gparent I need to know how i can create bridge between interfaces without IP address. I can't test this configuration on my server, so i ask for help.

Comment: You should test in a VM. Even if someone answers "yes", there's no guarantee that they are right and that you won't hit another problem when implementing it. At that point, you'll have a real question, and you can come back here to ask it. Essentially, to answer the question, we would have to do everything you would to implement the configuration.

Comment: @gparent Ок, i still have a real question, "how i can create bridge between interfaces without IP address". This is a real question?

Comment: Absolutely. At that point, we start from scratch and we don't need to assume that you consider the bridging configuration above correct. I'm not sure if the question is more fit for Superuser than Serverfault, but at least there's something to answer :)